# Ruby on rail migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a backup of ruby on rail server working with mysql databse.
backup Folder contain many subfolder like Vendor, node_modules, lib, config, bin, app, db, public and some files.
Now i have configured a new ubuntu server with fresh install of ubuntu server and ruby on rail is showing welcome page on port 3000 on server ip.
Can you guide how i can restore that backup app to this server so the app starts working from this new server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the root folders of the app to your new computer
2. with the terminal go to the root of the directory

   ```
   cd path/to/your/root/directory
   ```
3. check that you are in the root directory by running `pwd` in the terminal, it should return the root directory of your app
4. run the `bundle install` command in the terminal, it will install all the gems required for you app
5. trouble shoot potential errors by searching online for instructions, install all software required and read every error
6. run `rails s` and go to your webbrowser to test the development version of your app

Comment: How i restore the databse?
i mean it has 3 db in same user, prod , dev and test.

Comment: @adi `rake db:create:all`

Comment: @adi to create the database, the rest search online for instructions based on your db